# have variable for the rownum through multiple loop itarations

Tags: loops, xslt, row

I am producing a csv file in OIC using append option, in a loop, so each iteration of a loop the process writes to the same file, with a rownum column which is the sequential record number in the file, the way I do it in my XSLT is:

```
<xsl:variable name="Counter">
   <xsl:number level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
<ns33:RowNum>
   <xsl:value-of select="$Counter"/>
</ns33:RowNum>
```

or

```
<ns35:RowNum xml:id="id_286">
   <xsl:value-of select="position ()"/>
</ns35:RowNum>
```

What happens is, with example of 10 records in a loop,  in the first loop rownum takes values 1 .. 10, in the second loop 1 .. 10 again. In the csv file the rownum column have values 1 .. 10 1 .. 10. I want them to be 1 .. 20.
I have hard time figuring how to do that. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: P.S. Your question is tagged as `xslt`. There is no "append" option in XSLT and there is no memory of previous transformations. If (as it seems) your calling application performs a series of XSLT transformations, it must also pass the information about previous  transformations to the next.

Comment: It sounds like your "loop" is in OIC (presumably you mean Oracle Integration Cloud) rather than in your XSLT. So you will need to provide information about how you have configured OIC to invoke your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

In OIC, variable defined inside XSLT will be maintained within the scope of XSLT only. As you want to use a number consistent between different iterations of XSLT transformations, you will need a variable outside XSLT. This variable needs to be passed in as a parameter to XSLT.

Declare 1 variable in OIC level (outside the loop) and set it as 0.
As said before, it also passed as a parameter to XSLT.

Say the variable name as $externalCounter. Populate value of RowNum as below

```
<ns33:RowNum>
   <xsl:value-of select="$externalCounter + $Counter"/>
</ns33:RowNum>
```

After your xslt transformation, inside the loop, **update value of $externalCounter to maximum value of RowNum in XSLT output**. In your case, value of last nodeset should be sufficient.

```
$xsltOutput/..../RowNum[last()]
```